# How resize Map Icon when it already call through conditional array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My Marker[i][4] Array has two values P & R(P for Red Icon and R for Blue Icon) so now I want to make the big size of the red icon in comperision of blue icons.

This is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initMap() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
                
        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);
          
        var markers = [];
        var infoWindowContent = [];
        
        <?php   
        $query = "select id, dealer, lat, lon, dtype from dealer_m_testing where status = '1' and deleted is NULL"; 
        $query .= " order by seq asc";
        $dealers = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($dealers) > 0){
          $i=0;
          while($dealer = mysqli_fetch_array($dealers)){ ?>
            var marker = [];
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['id']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['dealer']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['lat']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['lon']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['dtype']; ?>');
            markers.push(marker);
            <?php
          }
        } ?>
        
        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
          var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3], markers[i][4]);
          bounds.extend(position);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            id: markers[i][0],
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][1],
            //icon: 'http://trivenialmirah.com/img/'+markers[i][4]+'.png'
            icon: { url: 'http://trivenialmirah.com/img/'+markers[i][4]+'.png',
            // for Red Icon make Big
            if(markers[i][4] == 'P'){ scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 32)}, 
            // for Blue Icon make small
            else {scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(11, 18)} },
            
          });
          
          // Allow each marker to have an info window    
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                showDetails(marker.id);
            }
          })(marker, i));
      
          // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
          
        }
                 
        // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
          //this.setZoom(1);
          google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });
        
      }
        
    </script>
```

at present using If condition for make big size for one icon but map screen not responding.

See my presently working this script without if condition.

[image: Please use this link for see work of this script before condition and here red icon, these icons should have to big size]

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code. Your conditional is inside an object definition.

Comment: please describe correct syntax for this script, Please

Comment: Please look at the errors reported in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

on this line:

```
if(markers[i][4] == 'P'){ scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 32)},
```

You can't put a conditional (if) statement in the middle of an object like you have in the code posted in your question.  Instead, either you can use a ternary operator:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  id: markers[i][0],
  position: position,
  map: map,
  title: markers[i][1],
  icon: { url: 'http://trivenialmirah.com/img/'+markers[i][4]+'.png',
  scaledSize: (markers[i][4] == 'P') ? new google.maps.Size(20, 32) : new google.maps.Size(11, 18)
  }, 
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a9fg27nv/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

Or create the object (either the Icon object, as below, or the complete MarkerOptions object) conditionally, then use it:

```
icon = { 
  url: 'http://trivenialmirah.com/img/'+markers[i][4]+'.png',
  // for Red Icon make small
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(11, 18)} 
};
if(markers[i][4] == 'P'){ 
  // for Blue Icon make small
  icon.scaledSize =new google.maps.Size(20, 32); 
}
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  id: markers[i][0],
  position: position,
  map: map,
  title: markers[i][1],
  icon: icon
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a9fg27nv/1/)

**code snippet (using the ternary operator):**

```js
function initMap() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };

  // Display a map on the page
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3], markers[i][4]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      id: markers[i][0],
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][1],
      //icon: 'http://trivenialmirah.com/img/'+markers[i][4]+'.png'
      icon: {
        url: 'http://trivenialmirah.com/img/' + markers[i][4] + '.png',
        scaledSize: (markers[i][4] == 'P') ? new google.maps.Size(20, 32) : new google.maps.Size(11, 18)
      },
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent("id:" + marker.id + "<br>" + this.getPosition().toUrlValue());
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

  // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    //this.setZoom(1);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
var markers = [];

var marker = [];
marker.push('id1');
marker.push('Palo Alto, CA');
marker.push(37.4418834);
marker.push(-122.1430195);
marker.push('P');
markers.push(marker);
var marker = [];
marker.push('id2');
marker.push('Mountain View, CA');
marker.push(37.3860517);
marker.push(-122.08385115);
marker.push('P');
markers.push(marker);
var marker = [];
marker.push('id3');
marker.push('Menlo Park, CA');
marker.push(37.4529598);
marker.push(-122.18172525);
marker.push('R');
markers.push(marker);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Dear Geocodezip Sir,
Yes! now it's working.

Thanks a lot for help us.